# how to do a loop in JS with 2 breaks

Tags: javascript

I want to do a loop with JS that has two breaks. For example, 1 to 9, and 15 to 29. Maybe a double loop?

Its a noob question I know, but i am a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: You can have 1 loop from 1-29 and only process if index is not between 10-14

Comment: Hi Juanlu, you can use a continue statement to make the loop skip the code following the continue command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a for loop like this:

```
for (var a = 0; a < 30; a++) {
  if (a >= 1 && a <= 9) {
    console.log("do this");
  }
  if (a >= 15 && a <= 29) {
    console.log("do that");
  }
}
```